# change the info part of each node in binary tree

Tags: data-structures

i have a binary tree.

```
         2
       /   \
      3     4
     / \     \
    5  1      8
     \       /
     6      9
```

I want to change the info part of each node such that the

```
nodeinfo = nodeinfo + nextInorderNodeInfo
```

so the actual inorder traversal

```
5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 9, 8
```

will change to

```
5+6,6+3,3+1,1+2,2+4,4+9,9+8,8+0 

11, 9,  4,  3,  6,  13, 17, 8
```

i need to write a function that will modify the binary tree info parts of each node.

i have done the following

calling

```
change(root,NULL);
```

function definition

```
void change(node* n, node *k)
{
 if (n) 
  { 
    if (n->left) change(n->left,n);
    if (n->right) change(n,n->right);
    n->info + = k->info;
  }
}
```

in this way i am not able to modify the nodes that are right hand leaf nodes.

can someone give the correct solution..???

thanks in advance

Comment: Seems more appropriate to the main stackexchange. I suggest you debug your code by going over small examples. Perhaps some statement is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, since you want to use the next info in the inorder traversal, you have to do a function that traverse you tree backward for this order.

```
    int change(node* n,int next){
     int k;
     k=next;
     if(n){
      if(n->right) k = change(n->right,next);
      if(n->left) change(n->left,n->info);
      n->info += k;
     }
    }
```

That way, calling

```
     change(root,0)
```

You have next that is the info of the next node in your order.

I hope I didn't made a mistake and that it help.